# End-to-end testing in React Native with Detox [does not render the assets and the images]

Tags: android, react-native, jestjs, mocha.js, detox

I'm new to the detox framework and end-to-end testing on react native.

I followed all the steps described in this tutorial (https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md)

I managed to start the "detox test", but unfortunately, I don't know why the apk generated, does not render the assets and the images correctly.

as you can see below the differences between the apk generated by detox and mocha, and the real apk generated by the react-native run-android command :

**apk generated by the react-native run-android command :**

[image]

**apk generated by the  command  detox build --configuration android.emu.debug :**

[image]

Is it like the "assets" that it did not generate correctly with the second command ?

Thanks you.